# On a random partition

Tags: pr.probability

Let $I=(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. We denote by $m$ the Lebesgue measure on $I$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we set $n^{-1}\mathbb{N}=\{k/n \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $I_n=I \cap n^{-1}\mathbb{N}$. Let $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be i.i.d random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. We assume that
\begin{align*}
P[X_1 \in A]=m(A),\quad A \in \mathcal{B}((0,1)).
\end{align*}

**Question.** For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \le k \le n$, we define $Y_k \in I_n$ in such a way that
\begin{align*}
\min_{x \in I_n}|X_k-x|=|X_k-Y_k|.
\end{align*}
Then, can we find positive numbers $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with the following  properties ?

1. $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\alpha_n=0$.
2. For large sufficiently $n$, we have $
   P\left[\max_{1 \le k \le n}|X_k-Y_k| \le \alpha_n \right]=1.$

This is a question of how uniform the partition determined by $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is.

For the requirement 2, it seems better to use the Borel--Cantelli lemma. However, I feel that it is a little difficult to calculate $\max_{1 \le k \le n}|X_k-Y_k|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fixed $n$ and $k \le n$ the distance $|X_k-Y_k|$ is uniformly distributed  in $[0,1/(2n)]$.  Thus
if $\alpha_n<1/(2n)$, then
$$P\left[\max_{1 \le k \le n}|X_k-Y_k| \le \alpha_n \right]=(1-2n\alpha_n)^n \,.
$$
On the other hand,  if $\alpha_n \ge 1/(2n)$, then this probability is clearly 1.
So this gives a negative answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. $|X_n-Y_n|$ is also uniformly distributed, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. I understood.